# Weird behavior of pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

When I compile the given code it doesn't produce any error or warnings. My question here is shouldn't the compiler produce error when compiling the following line `*err = "Error message";` because we are dereferencing a **pointer to pointer to constant char** and assigning a string to it.

Is it allowable to assign anything inside a pointer anything other than address and exactly what is happening in this given scenario?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set_error(const char**);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const char* err;
    set_error(&err);
    printf("%s",err);
    return 0;
}


void set_error(const char** err1) 
{
     *err1 = "Error message";
}
```

Comment: It's a `const char**`, you can modify the individual pointers (strings in the string array, conceptually), just not the characters of individual strings. You are thinking of `char * const *` (or something).

Comment: `err` is a non-const pointer to a non-const pointer to a const char.  So yes, you can modify it.

Comment: Frist question I see with complaining that there is no warning nor errors and everything works fine ;) (+1)

Comment: C and C++ are different programming languages. Pick one. Don't attempt to program in two different languages at the same time. A C program compiled on a C++ compiler will be crap, and a C++ program that only uses C programming practices will also be crap (from a C++ programmer's point of view).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const char** err1
```

That's a pointer to a non-constant pointer to a constant object. Dereferencing it gives a non-constant pointer (to a constant object), which can be assigned to.

To prevent assigning to the `const char*`, that would also have to be `const`:

```
const char * const * err1
```

Comment: Wow really subtle! I will always prefer STL containers any day.

Answer (score 4):

`"Error message"` is not a `std::string`. It's a `const char[]`. All string literals in C++ are `const char[]`. In C, they're `char[]`.

Comment: But in C, you should still treat them as if they have `const char[]` type. Everything else is poor programming practice.

Comment: @Lundin I would say that in C you _must_ still treat them as if they have `const char[]` type, because the implementation is allowed to put string literals into read-only memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it allowable to assign anything inside a pointer anything other than address and exactly what is happening in this given scenario?

You can assign pointer to a pointer. You think about pointer as an address, that's fine to understand concept, but do not mix it with data type. Data type is a pointer, not address. For example to assign address in memory to a pointer you need to cast it to a pointer:

```
char *pointer = reinterpret_cast<char *>( 0xA000000 );
```

You may ask how this would compile?

```
int array[10];
int *ptr = array;
```

That comes from C - array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element. So it is pointer to pointer assignment again. Now about string literal with double quotes. It  is an array as well:

```
const char str[] = "str";
const char str[] = { 's', 't', 'r', '\0' };
```

These 2 statements are pretty much the same. And as array can be implicitly converted to pointer to the first element it is fine to assign it to `const char *`